# sitecore web form for marketers - Send Mail action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

We are using Web Form for marketers to create forms which will send an email using fixed From address.I have added fixed From address into parameters field for Send Mail action.

Is there any way to pick up From address from actual field on the form? For e.g. if we have Email address field on form, can i use this email address as From address to send an email?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes, you can set the From field in e-mail from the Form. Ask one of your developers to help you with it.

Comment: @Tomislav: I know you can setup from email address inside Parameters field on /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Mail item. But how i can use a field(we can call EmailAddress) which user is going to type on actual form?

Comment: This indeed is a programmer question, because to catch a form field from Sitecore webforms you need to override the ProcessMessage class and hook it into the forms.config <processMessage> part (last pipeline). If you need any more assistance after reading Mark Usino's post, please give me a shout. I have got working code that does what you need.

Comment: In the WebFormForMarketers for Sitecore 6.5 when prepearing a mail send action you can in the email designer use [your_form_field_name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to expose a **From address** right on the front-end form for users to enter in. The out of the box mail action doesn't support this but you can use code from the Sitecore Shared Source [Extended Mail Action](http://trac.sitecore.net/WorkflowModules/wiki/MailDocumentation) to re-create it with this ability. The [source code is available](http://svn.sitecore.net/WorkflowModules/Trunk/MailWorkflowAction/sources/MailAction.cs) via Sitecore's SVN.

Comment: One caveat of setting the "from address" (not just in Webforms for marketers) is that not all mail servers enable Relay, which means that some mails will not get sent. Eg. trying to sende with the from address being obama@whitehouse.gov

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add your form field "from address" by open form editor and just add form field on click of "From" field. It will give you functionality to add your form field value.

Please see attached image.
[image]